# How to know the real eytomolgy for any kanji?

Tags: kanji

When i ask on this site for the eytomolgy for any kanji .somebody comes (like user called droooze) and answer my question by explaining the eytomolgy and giving a pictures of the kanji in the seal script or bone script ... etc 
My question is what is the source which those who answer my qustions take this information from?

Comment: This question is off-topic, but since you mentioned me specifically...I use Chinese-language references, and generally the same references as that used by [*Outlier Kanji*](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/johnrenfroe/outlier-kanji-dictionary). If you want **accurate** explanations, the only English resource I would recommend is Outlier's dictionary (although they haven't released their product yet, and probably won't present you with a glyph evolution sequence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One English-language source is The Complete Guide to Japanese Kanji.
[https://www.amazon.com/Complete-Guide-Japanese-Kanji-Understanding/dp/4805311703/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=Kanji&qid=1551571203&s=gateway&sr=8-6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/4805311703)